# Listview how to check the row above and below my Selected row and store the data from all three rows?

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I am working on a memory simulator for a variable partition system. I want am using c# to create a listview that will display the memory with the following rules:

1.FF allocation.

2.De-allocation with the four combination possibilities accounted for and demonstrated.

3.A free space status provided for every instance of #1 and #2 above.

4.A processing status on command (p#, size, and where located).

5.Garbage compaction as necessary.

6.Appropriate error msg when there is insufficient memory available AFTER compaction.

The issue I am having is when I attempt to reallocate the memory process. I need to check to see if there is free space above the partition I am reallocating and below the partition so that I can merge all the partitions free spaces into one partition. When I attempt to store the row above to check if its free and or below I am getting an error for

{"InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.\r\nParameter name: indexSystem.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

I can't seem to find another way to merge the above and below rows, if they have free space other then to use the following code:
string content2 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[-1]].SubItems[0].Text;

which gives the error. Is there an easier way to merge the rows and solve the error?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testone
{
    public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        int count = 1;
        int totalMBct = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            listView1.Columns.Add("P#", 80);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Size all in MB", 80);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Allocation Bit", 92);
            ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("Free Space");
            SetHeight(listView1, 256);
            item1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            item1.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
            item1.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item1,
            "1000 MB", Color.Black, Color.Yellow, item1.Font));
            item1.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item1,
            "        0", Color.Black, Color.White, item1.Font));
            listView1.Items.Add(item1);
        }

        private void SetHeight(ListView listView, int height)
        {
            ImageList imgList = new ImageList();
            imgList.ImageSize = new Size(1, height);
            listView1.SmallImageList = imgList;
        }
        private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                int iIndex = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index;
                string content = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]].SubItems[1].Text;
                string contentIF = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]].Text;
                int newTotalct = +int.Parse(content);
                string iIndex1 = iIndex.ToString();
                string counter1 = listView1.Items.Count.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("index " + iIndex1, "counter " + counter1 + " content" + totalMBct);
                if (contentIF != "Free Space" && totalMBct <= 1000 && iIndex != listView1.Items.Count - 1 && iIndex > 0)
                {
                    string content2 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[-1]].SubItems[0].Text;///LINE WHERE I GET ERROR NEED TO STORE CONTENT IN STRING!!
                    string content1 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[+1]].SubItems[0].Text;;///LINE WHERE I GET ERROR NEED TO STORE CONTENT IN STRING!!

                    MessageBox.Show("index " + iIndex1, " content" + content2);
                    if (content1 != "Free Space" && content2 != "Free Space")
                    {
                        listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.FocusedItem);
                        ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("Free Space");
                        item3.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                        item3.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                        item3.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubIte(item3,
                        content, Color.Black, Color.Yellow, item3.Font));
                        item3.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubIte(item3,
                        "        0", Color.Black, Color.White, item3.Font));
                        listView1.Items.Insert(iIndex, item3);
                        SetHeight(listView1, 256 / listView1.Items.Count);
                        totalMBct = totalMBct - newTotalct;
                        if (totalMBct < 1000)
                        {
                MessageBox.Show("Enabling button again memory less then full!"); 
                            button1.Enabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int userVal = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            totalMBct += userVal;

            if (totalMBct >= 1000)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The memory is Full no more entries!");
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }

            if (listView1.Items.Count > 1)
            {
                listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
            }
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Text = "P" + count;
            item.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
            item.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item,
            textBox1.Text, Color.Black, Color.LightSteelBlue, item.Font));
            item.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item,
            "        1", Color.Black, Color.White, item.Font));
            if (count == 1)
            {
                listView1.Items.Clear();
            }
            count++;
            listView1.Items.Add(item);

            if (totalMBct < 1000)
            {
                int NewFs = 1000 - totalMBct;
                string NewFs1 = NewFs.ToString();
                ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("Free Space");
                item2.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                item2.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                item2.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item2,
                NewFs1, Color.Black, Color.Yellow, item2.Font));
                item2.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item2,
                "        0", Color.Black, Color.White, item2.Font));
                listView1.Items.Add(item2);
                SetHeight(listView1, 256 / listView1.Items.Count);
            }

            textBox1.Clear();
        }
        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar&&char.IsDigit.KeyChar&&e.KeyChar= '.'))

            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            // only allow one decimal point
            if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') -1))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives what error? Did you try `listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]-1]` and `listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]+1]` ?

Comment: I am sure I did but I can try it again

Comment: that gives an error as well

Comment: See my updated comment. Also can explain what error you are getting? Which line of code gives error? Which item in the listview you are selecting?

Comment: you cant seem to use the -1 in this case because arrays start at [0] not -1 but the row I need is -1 to the current row I am selecting I just don't know a way of getting the info from the previous row to merge with the current row. If the previous row has free space of say 250 mb and the current row after I click it now has free space of 250 mb I need to merge those two rows into one row of 500 mb free space. This is what I am having an issue finding a solution too.

Comment: The line that gives the error has bold cc comments to the right of it you have to scroll over to see them

Comment: string content2 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[-1]].SubItems[0].Text;///LINE WHERE I GET ERROR NEED TO STORE CONTENT IN STRING!!
                    string content1 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[+1]].SubItems[0].Text;;///LINE WHERE I GET ERROR NEED TO STORE CONTENT IN STRING!!

Comment: Did you try listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]-1] and listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]+1]

Comment: that doesn't give the error but it always doesn't seem to work at all

Comment: hold on going to try to change some of my code for my if loops to see if it will work with your code

Comment: that seems to record the correct info but for some reason the                   if (content1 != "Free Space" && content2 != "Free Space") doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Can you debug and see what values are set to content1 and content2? What is your expectation?

Comment: okay so this is close but now I get the error for the plus +1 InvalidArgument=Value of '4' is not valid for 'index'.\r\nParameter name: index" System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException  the if statement I created only works for index greater then 0 which prevents it from causing the error but I also need one that makes sure if I click on the very last line it does not enter the if statement either if( iIndex > 0 && iIndex+1 != listView1.SelectedItems.Count) but this works good for index 0 but not for the second.

Comment: It should be `if ( iIndex > 0 && iIndex+1 < listView1.Items.Count) `

Comment: yes that worked thanks so much!

Comment: now I got to figure out all the other ones but this gives me a working  point so the rest should be easy